# How to assign a blank date field as default value to a ui-datepicker in Vue.js

Tags: date, vue.js

I have a `ui-datepicker` in vue.js and I want the field to be empty or blank as its default value.

```
<ui-datepicker
     label="Date"
     v-model="searchDate"
     :custom-formatter="picker9Formatter"
     :lang="picker12Lang">
</ui-datepicker>

export default {
    data(){
        searchDate : new Date(),
    }
}
```

With my code above, it returns the current date value. I have tried to do:

```
searchDate: '',
searchDate: moment('0000-00-00'),
```

but both of them throws an error saying:

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected Date, got String.

Now, how can I make a blank `datepicker` field?

Comment: Can you link to the documentation for that `ui-datepicker` component?

Comment: @Phil Yes, that's the one.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the link from my comment (was this one https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker). It looks like you should be able to set an initial empty string. Are you sure that's the component you're using? If so, what version? Can you show the entry from your `package.json` dependencies?

Comment: @Phil Will get back to you if I got some info, I'm currently exploring it since in my side, it throws an error when setting an empty string value. It works, but has an error.

Comment: @Phil Is there any way I can make a default value to date as `0000-00-00` instead ? Thanks.

Comment: @Phil I think it's not a good idea to set the default value as `1900-01-01` for the user will scroll to how many years before it can reach to its specified date, not user-friendly hahaha. My problem now is how to handle the error when assigning an empty string
.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you *actually are using* [this component](https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker), it sounds to me like you just want to set `"0000-00-00"` as the **placeholder**.

For example

```js
Vue.use(DatePicker.default); // don't worry about this, it's just for the demo

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    picker12Lang: 'en',
    searchDate: ''
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.21/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue2-datepicker@2.6.4/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <date-picker
       v-model="searchDate"
       :lang="picker12Lang"
       placeholder="0000-00-00">
  </date-picker>
  <pre>searchDate = {{ searchDate }}</pre>
</div>
```

FYI, the current version of that component no longer supports the `custom-formatter` prop.

As for the error message...

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected Date, got String.

I can't see that in anything I've tried so it must be coming from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign default date as new Date(0);

Comment: Thanks for this one, but it displays to `1970-01-01`.

Comment: @ramj Yes it will. There is not such black date concept as of i know, It will start from somewhere like 1970-01-01

Comment: You mean, blank date for black date?

Comment: @ramj By passing empty value if it is working, then you can leave it with console exception. We don't have other option.

Comment: How can I apply console exemption to my v-model?